# Change the name of rows in Python

Tags: python, rename, series

I would like to change the name of my rows in python.
I got the means of a dataframe via

```
df10mean = df10.mean()
```

This was my output:

```
1-      256.098455
1+      302.581844
2-    19116.212118
2+    23312.823240
3-     1484.770812
3+     1689.325187
4-     1412.037664
4+     2042.475828
5-     1109.064987
5+     1604.215015
6-     1165.800898
6+     1390.945443
7-    19309.453761
7+    24180.334620
dtype: float64
```

Now I wanted to rename the first column. I tried it via

```
df10mean3 = df10mean2.rename(columns={'1-': 'EVC -', '1+': 'EVC +', '2-': 'RBS* mVenus -', '2+': 'RBS* mVenus +',
                           '3-': 'H56-1 mVenus -', '3+': 'H56-1 mVenus +', '4-': 'H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 -',
                            '4+': 'H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 +', '5-': 'H56-2 mVenus -', '5+': 'H56-2 mVenus +',
                            '6-': 'H56-2 mVenus + T56-0 -', '6+': 'H56-2 + T56-0 +', '7-': 'RBS* mVenus T56-0 -',
                                 '7+': 'RBS* mVenus T56-0 +'}, inplace = true)
```

The output gives me the same column names as before. It didn't change anything.

I tried to fix this problem for two days now. Could you please help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need change `columns` to `index` because working with `Series` and there are no columns and remove `inplace=True` if assign to new variable:

```
df10mean3 = df10mean2.rename(index=d)
```

Or omit it:

```
d = {'1-': 'EVC -', '1+': 'EVC +', 
'2-': 'RBS* mVenus -', '2+': 'RBS* mVenus +',
'3-': 'H56-1 mVenus -', '3+': 'H56-1 mVenus +', 
'4-': 'H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 -', '4+': 'H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 +',
'5-': 'H56-2 mVenus -', '5+': 'H56-2 mVenus +',
'6-': 'H56-2 mVenus + T56-0 -', '6+': 'H56-2 + T56-0 +', 
'7-': 'RBS* mVenus T56-0 -', '7+': 'RBS* mVenus T56-0 +'}

df10mean3 = df10mean2.rename(d)
print (df10mean3)
EVC -                       256.098455
EVC +                       302.581844
RBS* mVenus -             19116.212118
RBS* mVenus +             23312.823240
H56-1 mVenus -             1484.770812
H56-1 mVenus +             1689.325187
H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 -     1412.037664
H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 +     2042.475828
H56-2 mVenus -             1109.064987
H56-2 mVenus +             1604.215015
H56-2 mVenus + T56-0 -     1165.800898
H56-2 + T56-0 +            1390.945443
RBS* mVenus T56-0 -       19309.453761
RBS* mVenus T56-0 +       24180.334620
dtype:                         float64
Name: col, dtype: object
```

---

For `inplace=True` is renamed original `Series`:

```
df10mean2.rename(d, inplace=True)
print (df10mean2)
EVC -                       256.098455
EVC +                       302.581844
RBS* mVenus -             19116.212118
RBS* mVenus +             23312.823240
H56-1 mVenus -             1484.770812
H56-1 mVenus +             1689.325187
H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 -     1412.037664
H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 +     2042.475828
H56-2 mVenus -             1109.064987
H56-2 mVenus +             1604.215015
H56-2 mVenus + T56-0 -     1165.800898
H56-2 + T56-0 +            1390.945443
RBS* mVenus T56-0 -       19309.453761
RBS* mVenus T56-0 +       24180.334620
dtype:                         float64
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: How do I insert my old names and my new names in your code`? I don't really understand your advice...

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just got it with the help of jezrael.
I used this code:

```
df10mean3 = df10mean2.rename(index={'1-': 'EVC -', '1+': 'EVC +', '2-': 'RBS* mVenus -', '2+': 'RBS* mVenus +',
                           '3-': 'H56-1 mVenus -', '3+': 'H56-1 mVenus +', '4-': 'H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 -',
                            '4+': 'H56-1 mVenus + T56-0 +', '5-': 'H56-2 mVenus -', '5+': 'H56-2 mVenus +',
                            '6-': 'H56-2 mVenus + T56-0 -', '6+': 'H56-2 + T56-0 +', '7-': 'RBS* mVenus T56-0 -',
                                 '7+': 'RBS* mVenus T56-0 +'})
```

Thank you very much!